# Kentico 9 blog main page, archive page, and tag page

Tags: kentico

I'm new to Kentico, and have spent hours trying to make the blog work but haven't had any luck. Hope someone could help. I created a new blog by [a] using Pages > New Page > Blog;  [b] then applying the Blog page template to it; [c] after that I created 2 sample blog posts. The only thing that works is the individual blog post. Other things don't work:

1- the blog main page --> empty

2- the blog archive page (for July) --> empty

3- tag link --> error message "Page /Blogs/My-blog-1.aspx was not found." Although I know I can change the tag link url, not sure what should be in there.

4 - making "Blog" appears on my nav (that I used CSS List menu web part). For this one, as a workaround, I was thinking about adding a blank "Blog" page and had it redirected to the blog url.

I've read the documentation related to Blog, but couldn't make it to work. Thanks for help!

[image: Screenshot of blog configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the out of the box templates are setup in such a way to only work on some of the example site templates which is why you're getting these results.

1. In the rptAllPosts repeater, set the [Path property](https://docs.kentico.com/display/k8/Writing+document+path+expressions) to `./%`, ensure the Page types property is set to `cms.blogpost`, make sure you have a value in the Transformation property as well.
2. Should be resolved when you finish #1
3. You will have to modify the Selected Transformation.  If you're using the default transformation, about line 9, way at the end you will need to modify the last parameter from `~/Blogs/my-blog-1.aspx` to `~/Blog`.  This should fix the blog tag link.
4. Your work-around is very common and I'd stick with it for now.

Comment: Thank you Brenden for the quick and clear answer! Much appreciated!